# EGL: programmatically select contents of dojocurrencytextbox

Tags: dojo, egl

Updated with new code.

I searched through this forum already but cannot find the solution to my problem (perhaps I'm using the wrong search criteria).
What I'm looking for is a way to select the contents of a DojoCurrencyTextbox via code (programmatically).
I created a testprogram, and when I click on the currencytextbox The contents is selected (via the selectonClick property). And also when I push a button I can set the focus to the currencytextbox, but I seem unable to select the contents, for the DOjoTextField it does work, but for the DojoCurrencyTextBox it doesn't.

I hope that someone can tell me how I can get this functionality working.

The testcode I use is the following:

```
package dmg.zz_testruben;

// RUI Widget

import com.ibm.egl.rui.widgets.GridLayout;
import com.ibm.egl.rui.widgets.GridLayoutData;
import egl.ui.rui.Event;
import dojo.widgets.DojoButton;
import dojo.widgets.DojoCurrencyTextBox;
import dojo.widgets.DojoTextField;


handler TestSelectCurrencyTextBox type RUIWidget {targetWidget = ui, onConstructionFunction = start}
    ui GridLayout{ columns = 3, rows = 4, cellPadding = 4, children = [txtInput1, btnInput1, btnInput1b, txtInput2, btnInput2, btnInput2b] };

    txtInput1 DojoTextField{layoutData = new GridLayoutData{row=1, column=1}, suppressChangeEvent = true, selectOnClick = true, text = "abc"};
    btnInput1 DojoButton{layoutData = new GridLayoutData{row=1, column=2}, text = "select", onClick ::= btnInput1_onClick};
    btnInput1b DojoButton{layoutData = new GridLayoutData{row=1, column=3}, text = "focus", onClick ::= btnInput1b_onClick};
    txtInput2 DojoCurrencyTextbox{layoutData = new GridLayoutData{row=2, column=1}, suppressChangeEvent = true, selectOnClick = true, text = "1,23"};
    btnInput2 DojoButton{layoutData = new GridLayoutData{row=2, column=2}, text = "select", onClick ::= btnInput2_onClick};
    btnInput2b DojoButton{layoutData = new GridLayoutData{row=2, column=3}, text = "focus", onClick ::= btnInput2b_onClick};

    function start()
    end 



    private function btnInput1_onClick (e Event in)
        txtInput1.children[2].children[1].select();
    end

    private function btnInput2_onClick (e Event in)
        txtInput2.children[2].children[1].select();
    end

    private function btnInput1b_onClick (e Event in)
        txtInput1.focus();
    end

    private function btnInput2b_onClick (e Event in)
        txtInput2.focus();
    end


end
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `select` on CurrencyTextBox's `focusNode`:

```js
require([
  "dojo/on",
  "dijit/form/CurrencyTextBox",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function(on, CurrencyTextBox) { 
  var ctb = new CurrencyTextBox({
    value: "54.12",
    constraints:{fractional:true},
    currency:'USD',
    invalidMessage:'Invalid amount. Cents are required.'
  }).placeAt("result");
  
  ctb.focusNode.select();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.12.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: What programming language is this? It's not EGL as far as I can see, for in EGL there is no focusNode membervariable for a CurrencyTextBox. Can you please give me some more explanation.

Comment: It's javascript - dojo library is written in it. Dojo api doesn't mention `focusNode`, but it is a reference to input node. I guess you should be able to call `txtInput2.focusNode.select();`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. When I change the code in the btnInput2_onClick function to the following: txtInput2.children[2].children[1].select(); (This now really points to the inputnode) than a select only focusses the inputbox, it does not select the contents.

Comment: Weird... Calling `select` on `input` element should select content -
 see [w3schools demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_select). This looks like `focus` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_text_focus.asp) got invoked on your input.

Comment: It is weird indeed, perhaps a bug in the dojo library?

Comment: It has to be EGL issue, if I change `ctb.focusNode.select();` to `ctb.domNode.children[1].children[0].select();` text is also selected. I've found similar thread on [EGL forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014675313).

Comment: The problem is that I cannot access the .domNode of .focusNode from my code it simply will not compile because it is not accessible from EGL. And the other thread you are referring to I already found, but it gives no solution to my problem. Thanks for your help so far.